# variables are not updating after control+C in a batch file

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop

I have the following code, a mix of batch and linux-dos (gawk command).  I do not have the source (sortgrad with options -d -v -g -r), so no control on it. The code works well except when sortgrad freezes, then I have to use control+C and it continues working in the following directory but it does not update input options (variables) in sortgrad.
Then I have two problems, how to continue the for loop without control+C when it is necessary and the problem of upadating variables.  Thanks

---

```
for /f "eol= " %%i in (tests) do ( 

cd %%i
echo.2 > input
echo.y >> input
echo.1 >> input
echo.%%i.out >> input

gawk "{print $1}" data > v
gawk "{print $2}" data > g

set /p grad= < g
set /p vel= < v

echo %grad% | gawk "{print $1-0.03}" > g1
echo %grad% | gawk "{print $1+0.03}" > g2
set /p gmin= < g1
set /p gmax= < g2

cmd.exe /C "sortgrad -d vanloc.dvr -v %vel% 7.0 -g %gmin% %gmax% -r 1.70 1.80" < "input" > result

cd..)
```

---

Comment: just an idea:  what happens if you place the statements of your for Loop in a subroutine and CALL it?  ie for /f "eol= " %%i in (tests) do 'call :sub'

Answer (score 0):

The variables are being set, but you are not accessing them properly.

Normal expansion of `%grad%` occurs at parse time, and the entire parenthesized block in your FOR loop is parsed in one pass. So `%grad%` remains a constant value - the value that existed before the loop started.

This is what delayed expansion was designed for. Put `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` at the top, and then access your variables as `!grad!`

Comment: batch working with the instructions. Thanks. Control+C still needed if program freezes. Is there any way to control elapsed time (of not working) to finish a process (exe) and continue with the next loop?